# Refresh a DataGridView on update to its list data source

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

In my current implementation I'm using a data grid view that is fed from a list of objects. 
I'm trying to add new entries, by adding new objects to the list.

I'm finding that when these new entries are added to the list, they do not appear in the DataGridView. I've tried updating it, clearing it and refilling it. All to know avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This was solved by using a binding source like so.

```
Dim bs As New BindingSource
bs.DataSource = Entries
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```

And then reassigning the data source each time.

```
Public Sub Grid_Update()
    bs = New BindingSource
    bs.DataSource = Entries
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
End Sub
```

Comment: you might want a `BindingList` or simply update/reset the datasource each time the list changes

Comment: I just figured it out on my own. The trick is to use a BindingSource object and do as malkam suggest below and re-assign the data source. On each change.

Comment: if you use a `BindingList(of T)` the refresh thing is not needed - it is what the list does.

Comment: I don't have BindingList available in my version of visual studio (2005). But good for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: actually, you do - import `System.ComponentModel`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Re assign grid source to updated list of objects and call databind method again.